# Measure of a set

Tags: measure-theory

I need to find that the measure of the following set A. Let 
$\Sigma=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the sequence space and we set

$A=\{(a_n)\in\Sigma:\mbox{ $a_{j}a_{j+1}=(01)$ for infinite many j} \}$ we define a measure $\mu[a_1a_2\cdots a_n]=\frac{1}{2^n}$, where $[a_1a_2\cdots a_n]=\{(b_k):b_1b_2\cdots b_n=a_1a_2\cdots a_n\}$ is the cylinder of $\Sigma$. prove that $\mu(A)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better prove that $\mu(\Sigma-A)=0$, considering that the sequences in $\Sigma-A$ are the eventually constant ones (of course you have to prove it too).

Comment: the difficult part is (01) can be appears at arbitrary location

Comment: And that's exactly the reason of $\Sigma - A$ being the eventually constant sequences.

Comment: Hint, hint... there are a finite number of sequences that are constant after index $n$. (why?)

Comment: So, the cardinality of the set of all the eventually constant sequences is...?

Comment: Then mark as correct answer please